# how to write the script for already registered username/email_id in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

My Java

```
public class Verifyregistration {
    String Verifyregistration_Status = null;
    String Verifyregistration_Message = null;

    @Test
    @Parameters({"USERNAME", "NAME", "EMAIL", "CHOOSEPASS", "CONFIRMPASS"})
    public void Execute(String UserName, String Name, String Email, String Choose_Pass, String Confirm_Pass) {
        try {

            Config.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register")).click();
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_username")).sendKeys(UserName);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("field_1")).sendKeys(Name);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_email")).sendKeys(Email);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_password")).sendKeys(Choose_Pass);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_password_confirm")).sendKeys(Confirm_Pass);
            Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_submit")).click();
            //perform validation here
            boolean expvalue = Config.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='signup_username']/preceding-sibling::*[1]")).isDisplayed();
            if (expvalue) {
                Verifyregistration_Status = "PASS";
                Verifyregistration_Message = "Sorry, that username already exists!";
            }
        } catch (Exception generalException) {
            Verifyregistration_Status = "FAIL";
            Verifyregistration_Message = "Verify Registration Successfull";
        } finally {
            Assert.assertTrue(Verifyregistration_Message, Verifyregistration_Status.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS"));
        }
    }
}
```

I have write above script for checking the registration of already username/email_id.I am just checking the registration of already registered username from error message.So my question is,i am going right or there will be another logic for checking registration of already username/emailid.Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use below code ,

public class Verifyregistration {

```
String Verifyregistration_Status = null;
String Verifyregistration_Message = null;

@Test
@Parameters({ "USERNAME", "NAME", "EMAIL", "CHOOSEPASS", "CONFIRMPASS" })
public void Execute(String UserName, String Name, String Email,
        String Choose_Pass, String Confirm_Pass) {

    // Below loop will execute two times
    // First Iteration , registration should be successful
    // Second Iteration Registration should fail saying "already registered" as i am using same data

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        Config.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register")).click();
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_username")).sendKeys(
                UserName);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("field_1")).sendKeys(Name);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_email")).sendKeys(Email);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_password")).sendKeys(
                Choose_Pass);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_password_confirm"))
                .sendKeys(Confirm_Pass);
        Config.driver.findElement(By.id("signup_submit")).click();
        // perform validation here
        boolean expvalue = Config.driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath("//input[@id='signup_username']/preceding-sibling::*[1]"))
                .isDisplayed();

        if (i==0) {

            Assert.assertFalse(expvalue);

        }else{

            Assert.assertTrue(expvalue);

        }


    }
}
```

}